Vox Populi stuck at 39 and failed
I was decided to read algebraic attacks and gave points as usual. I got the Suffrage badge. Vox Populi badge continued as I continue. It stuck at 39 and did not allow me to gave any points. Now, it was reset. I think there is a glitch somewhere.

You may want to note that the counter probably resets at 0:00 UTC which may not be 0:00 in your timezone. But did it actually tell you that you can't vote anymore and didn't award the badge?

I'm aware of the timezone issue. It is not, in this case.Yes, it warned me that, I cannot vote anymore. Tell me to wait for 60mins around... I was at 39 votes. After waiting. Vox Populi was reset to 1.

Can you try and check whether this issue is reproducible (ideally also check on other sites)?

:), maybe another day, while reading another tag.

These kind of questions are generally better asked at https://meta.stackexchange.com as they are generally identical across all SE sites.

I found the answer from meta.stackexchange 

You only get 40 votes in a day if a sufficiently high ratio of your
  votes are on questions. If you vote on only answers, you'll run out
  after 30 votes.
The more questions you vote on, the more votes over 30 you'll get.
Bottom line: The Vox Populi badge requires you to vote on a lot of
  questions during the day you earn it.


Assuming that indeed all the votes were given before 0:00 UTC, which may not be 0:00 in your timezone, I'd suggest for now that you retry getting that badge and if you face the same issue again (and thus it's reproducible), we'll escalate it to SE staff so they can fix it.
